# BlackBerry client authenticating to Java Web Service

Tags: appsec, authentication, passwords, hash, java

I already asked this question at StackOverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970681/blackberry-app-security and was directed to this site, can anyone pitch in as to how I can solve this issue?

---

Users log in to my BlackBerry app with a username and password provided at registration. My app connects to a Java Web Service that does all the logic.

- How do I go about storing the password and username in a safe manner on my server? Everybody says salting and hashing, but I have no idea how to do this since I've never worked with it. How can I do this in Java?
- How do I manage sending the password securely from the app to the server?

Comment: I modified the title, to make the focus of the question clearer. It's likely that it wasn't being read because of "Blackberry"... and it's really a question about the Java WS.

Comment: And how do you securely store the password on the BlackBerry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good explanation of this on the OWASP website, see the page [Hashing Java](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java).
It explains some of the details about the use of hashes and why to add a salt, it also contain code examples. This may be a good point for you to start from.

As for securing sending the passwords from the app using HTTPS instead of HTTP if your not already would be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised we haven't found a widely adopted standard implementation of this for Java.  It is such an important topic, and crypto code can be very tricky to get right and keep updated against the ever-improving attacks out there.

I'm glad to see that as of Java 6 there is an implementation of PBKDF2: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 in SunJCE.
See also the discussion of using the PBKDF2 standard (*not* PBKDF1) in a recent [PBKDF1 question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/is-pbkdf1-based-system-cryptology-passwordderivebytes-better-than-a-typical-h).  And as discussed in the answers to your question at StackOverflow, for earlier versions of Java, an implementation of that is at [A free Java implementation of RFC 2898 / PKCS#5 PBKDF2](http://rtner.de/software/PBKDF2.html)

There is also a Java answer (use [jBCrypt - strong password hashing for Java](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)), and some helpful discussion of the general issues for password hashing, at [Reference implementation of C# password hashing and verification - IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/reference-implementation-of-c-password-hashing-and-verification).

The OWASP sample code referred to in another answer does not seem as carefully described or  vetted as I would hope, but I haven't compared it with the others.

Comment: There is also apache commons libraries and classes org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils that have hashing methods for several formats and are easy to use and also allow for the creation of salts.